# How to resolve this "unreachable code after return statement" warning?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to learn the basics of angularjs and am working with the tutorial app and ng-js v1.6.6. Although the items show up (localhost), the browser shows a warning as seen in the screengrab. Chrome doesn't show the error-firefox does. Is the code okay or are there errors on line 17 / line 50?

```
   'use strict';

    angular.module('components.phone')
    .factory('Phone', ['$resource', function($resource,) {
    return $resource('components/phone/data/phones/:phoneId.json', {}, { 
        query: {
            method:'GET', 
            params: { phoneId:'phones' },
            isArray: true
            }
        }
      )    

     return factory;//<======LINE 17 -IS THE REST OF THE CODE 'UNREACHABLE'?
     }])

.service('PhoneService', ['$q','$http', '$resource', function($q, $http) {
    var service = { 
        get: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();

            $http.get('components/phone/data/phones/phones.json', { 
                params: { phoneId:'phones' } 
            })
            .then(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response.data);
            })
            .catch(function(response){
                deferred.resolve(response);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        },

        getAllPhones: function() {
            return $http.get('components/phone/data/phones/:phoneId.json', { 
                cache:   true }
            ).then(function(resp) {
                return resp.data;
            });
        },

        getPhone: function(phoneId) {
                for (i = 0; i < phones.length; i++) {
                    if(phones[i].id == phoneId){
                    this.phone = phones[i];
                     break; <==== THIS SYNTAX IS NOW CHANGED, THANKS@SYNCRO!


        return  $http.get('components/phone/data/phones/' +    $stateParams.phoneId + '.json')
                    .then(function(response) {
                        self.phone = response.data;

                    })
            }

            return service.getAllPhones().then(function (getPhone) {
                return selected.phone;
            })
        }
    }

    return service;
}])

.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
    function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
        $rootScope.$state = $state;
        $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
    }  
])
```

[image: Console error in FF]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `getPhone` method, if you `return` inside a for loop, the code after the `for` loop will be not executed, that's why your browser is alerting you with this warning message.

You can see this message also in Chrome, you just have to change the Log priority in your Chrome DevTools.

You can see that return problem in this little script that I wrote for you: https://jsfiddle.net/kmy7hq8q/

To leave the loop you just have to use `break`, not `return`.

```
if(phones[i].id == phoneId){
    this.phone = phones[i];
    break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but *if...break* didn't fix it.Still getting the same warning..

Comment: Do you get just one warning or two?

PS: Can you please indent the code correctly and place a comment on the lines where you get the warning? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Just found out that the *unreachable code after line 50* warning has now disappeared. Line 17 warning is still there. It's right at the top - *return factory* is line 17. Have flagged Line 17, and re-indented.

Comment: The problem is not in the line 17, it's before the line 17. You have to remove this return statement: `return $resource('....')`. A good IDE with the correct plugins/addons for your development stack (AngularJS) can help a lot :)

Comment: Ticked with thanks. Care to name any suitable IDE? I'm using *Microsoft Expression Web* and a Browser Extension called *200/OK* for localhost.

Comment: I suggest PhpStorm by JetBrains, Visual Studio Code and Atom. I use PhpStorm, it's really well done and helps a lot.